# Which component life cycle gets called everytime the screen mounts in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am bringing the images from firebase. The first time my home screen opens my app is working fine but when I go to some other screen and come back to the home screen only one image gets loaded which is the last image in the firebase. My sole purpose is to bring the images from firebase and show the images on the home page through flatlist. In the very first time it happens, but when I navigate to some other screen through drawer and come back again then only the last img is called from the firebase.

```
 export default class Home extends React.Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          backgroundImageUrl : [],
        }
      }
    
    
    
      static navigationOptions = {
        header: null ,
        headerForceInset: {vertical: 'never'},
      };
    
    
    
    componentWillMount()
      {
        firebase.database().ref().child("Card_Images/").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    
          
          this.setState({
            backgroundImageUrl : [...this.state.backgroundImageUrl, snapshot.val()],
          })
        }.bind(this))
      
      }
    
      
        
    
    
        handleTap = () => {
          //  console.log("item", item);this.props.screenProps.navigation.navigate("ItemDetails",
          this.props.navigation.navigate("ItemDetails")};
          
        renderItem = ({ item }) => {
          return (
           
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer}
            onPress = {this.handleTap}>
    
            <View style = {{height:180,width:Dimensions.get('window').width-32,marginLeft:16,marginRight:16,backgroundColor: 'black',marginTop: 16,marginBottom:16,
         borderRadius: 16}}>
          
           <Image
                        style={{
                         width:Dimensions.get('window').width-32,
                         height:160,
                         resizeMode:"cover",
                         alignSelf: 'center',
                         borderRadius:8,
                       
                        }}
                        source = {{ uri: item }}
                        //onPress = {() => this.selectCity()}
                      />
        
        <View style = {styles.DesignInformation}>
                    <Text style={{color:'grey',fontSize: 10,fontWeight:"bold",marginLeft:2}}> Rishavh Gupta </Text>
                    <Text style={{color:'grey',textAlign:"right",fontSize: 10,fontStyle: 'italic',marginRight:8,
                    shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: -1 }, elevation:4,borderBottomColor:'white',borderBottomWidth:0.8,shadowColor: "gray",shadowOpacity: 0.5,shadowRadius: 4}}>www.cometgraphic.com </Text>
    
        </View>
        
                    </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        };
    
      render() {
        console.log("images are", this.state.backgroundImageUrl)
        // console.log("sd", this.state.backgroundImageUrl)
    
    
        return (
                <View style = {styles.container}>
    
    
                <FlatList 
          data={this.state.backgroundImageUrl}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          numColumns={numColumns}
           />
```

Comment: You'll need to maintain history.

Comment: history, how?  Can you please elaborate I am very much confused.

Answer (score 1):

To debug the problem I would like to know number of entries your array of images is containing second time
Alternatively you can save the list in your redux store instead of keeping it in your component's state.

Comment: temporarily my total no of images in firebase is 8.. at the first time it shows total 8 images but after going from one navigation to other navigation and coming back it shows only one image....

Comment: is it making fetching 8 images in second instance in response. You might be overriding the old entries and storing last one while destructuring response.

Comment: i solved it though, it was a simple mistake.. I passed the value in the array and then that array as a value to set the state.

Comment: :D
that is great then